# 2 Dimension Passing (missing subscript, unknown size)

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I am constantly getting a missing subscript and unknown size problem. So, I am guessing this is a beginner problem but I can't get my head around it. How do I get my function to work and outputted to the screen?

I am trying to have two columns be filled with numbers. Column[0] is inputted by rand() and then have Column[1] be converted into a new number through an equation. I am expecting 1-10 rows to be inputted.

```
// function prototypes
void arrayProgram(double ma[][2], int xSize);

int main()
{
const int arraySize = 5;
double ma[arraySize][arraySize];
// if I change double ma[1][2]; 
// I get an argument of type 'int' is incompatible of type "double(*)[2]

arrayProgram(ma, arraySize);
}//end main

void arrayProgram(double ma[][2], int xSize)
{

    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < xSize; ++i)
    {
        ma[i][0] = rand();
        ma[i][1] = (ma[i][0] * (20 / 25.0) + 64);
    }

}
```

Comment: _" How do I get my function to work"_ Well one of the things is to edit your post and tell us what behavior it's exhibiting and what behavior you are expecting.

Comment: Is that code going to compile? Where's your types in the function declaration?

Comment: @Bhok  The array must be declared at least like double ma[1][2] .;

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I tried that and I am getting an int(*[2] is incompatible with parameter of type "double(*)[2]

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Thank you, I edited my post to reflect the updates.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh It doesn't compile. I edited my post to include the prototype.

Comment: @M.M Could to elaborate a little more please? I edited my post to better reflect the code.

Comment: `double ma[arraySize][arraySize];` resolves to `double ma[5][5];`. `arrayProgram` requires `double ma[<don't care>][2]`. `5 != 2`

Comment: @Bhok you should post the exact code that gives the error in the first place (if you still have not compiled exactly what you posted, go and do that now and check the error message is the same)

Comment: @user4581301 Oh, that makes a lot of sense. I changed the [arraySize][arraySize] to [1][2], but I still have a compiler problem.

Comment: Missing `#include <cstdlib>`? Only compiler error I see left. Need a call to `srand`, but that's not a compiler error. By the way, [take a look at `std::uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

// function prototypes
void arrayProgram(double ma[][2], int xSize);

int main()
{
const int arraySize = 1;
double ma[arraySize][2];

srand ( time(NULL) ); // setting seed value
rand(); // first random number

arrayProgram(ma, arraySize);
}//end main

void arrayProgram(double ma[][2], int xSize)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < xSize; ++i)
    {
        ma[i][0] = rand();
        ma[i][1] = (ma[i][0] * (20 / 25.0) + 64);
        std::cout << ma[i][0] << '\t' << ma[i][1] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: It compiles. Works is something else again. The results of `rand` will be always be the same. The same effect in C as calling `srand(1)`. Modern C++ Standard doesn't say much on the topic, so I'm assuming C holds.

Comment: Thanks. I was changed an answer.